# MySQL join not working

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_event_entries.race_nbr,
                tbl_event_entries.class_id,
                tbl_event_entries.racer_id,
                tbl_event_entries.heat_position,
                tbl_event_classes.combine
FROM tbl_event_entries
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_classes
ON tbl_event_entries.class_id = tbl_event_classes.class_id
WHERE tbl_event_entries.event_id = :event_id
ORDER BY tbl_event_entries.race_nbr, tbl_event_entries.heat_position
```

The data that this is in this query is :

```
event_class_id     event_id                     class_id    combine
822                20160706MAS577d098260173     1           2
823                20160706MAS577d098260173     2           8888


entry_id    event_id                    racer_id  class_id  
8318        20160706MAS577d098260173    238       1 
8319        20160706MAS577d098260173    1184      2
```

The output that I get from this query:

```
race_nbr class_id racer_id  heat_position combine
1        1        238       1             2
1        1        238       1             NULL
2        2        1184      1             8888 
2        2        1184      1             NULL
```

I can limit the query to not show "NULL" in combined, but I don't always have data in that field. But, I should never see duplicated rows like this.

I should see just two rows:

```
race_nbr class_id racer_id  heat_position combine
1        1        238       1             2
2        2        1184      1             8888
```

Can anyone see the error?

I have tried LEFT JOIN, JOIN and a few different changes with the fields. Not seeing why this is returning the invalid data..

Comment: are you sure that you provided real query and real data samples? your query part `tbl_event_entries.race_nbr,` not presented in data samples for example

Comment: Yes, the data is not complete. The query returns data that is not relevant to this question. I updated the query.

Comment: and what about `tbl_event_entries.race_nbr`?

Comment: your question is not complete, if we run query with data provided everything is fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1edd69/6 So you just need to provide more correct data first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Use aggregation...

```
SELECT e.race_nbr
     , e.class_id
     , e.racer_id
     , e.heat_position
     , MAX(c.combine) combine
  FROM tbl_event_entries e
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_event_classes c
    ON c.class_id = e.class_id 
 WHERE e.event_id = :event_id
 GROUP
    BY e.race_nbr
     , e.class_id
     , e.racer_id
     , e.heat_position
 ORDER 
    BY e.race_nbr
     , e.heat_position
```

Comment: A useful answer should explain what was wrong in the original code and how the answer fixes it. Just posting a bunch of code with no explanation is not as helpful.

Comment: Even though there is no explanation, I get what he's trying to show me.